# "by as much as" + number

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

> “The authors of the study, one of the most closely watched overviews of the global high-end retail market, predicted that such expansion would drive up growth across the global luxury market **by as much as 8 percent**.”

My question: what does **"by as much as 8 percent"** mean? Does it mean **"by 8 percent"** or **"by up to 8 percent"**?

Comment: It means it ***may be*** that much (which by implication is a relatively high value in the given context). But if it's not *exactly* that much, the implication is that it will be somewhat ***less***, not ***more***. If in your context the speaker thought a value of, say, 9% was at least *feasible*, he'd have cited the higher value, since the whole point of the construction is to emphasise how high the value *might* be.

Comment: The ***as much as X*** construction is more or less equivalent to ***up to X***, but imho that second alternative has *slightly* stronger implications the it won't be *higher* than X. That's simply because the phrasing suggests a predefined limit that perhaps can't be exceeded for some unspecified reason, whereas in the first version the value of X is usually just "the highest value the speaker thinks could reasonably apply", but it's always possible his opinion on that could turn out to be conservative.

Answer (score 2):

"by as much as X percent" is a way of discussing uncertainty. The author doesn't want to guarantee a particular number, and prefers to merely suggest that maybe this will be the value, and probably not more.

> does it mean "by up to 8 percent"?

Yes. Very close. As noted in earlier comments "The as much as X construction is more or less equivalent to up to X, but imho that second alternative has *slightly* stronger implications the it won't be higher than X."

> does it mean "by 8 percent"?

No. That would be stating an exact number.

Occasionally an advertisement will say "by as much as X percent, or even more!", which if carefully analyzed means they are saying *absolutely nothing*, and the number could be *anything*.